# Node Webkit - z-index?

Tags: css, featherlight.js

Ok so I have a node webkit app I am creating. I made a header div that stretches across the top with custom controls. I made the header div an app drag region so users can move the app around on screen.

I have now added featherbox and am creating a config screen.

When the lightbox is activated the appropriate area (the entire app) darkens as intended, but the draggable div doesn't interupt the lightbox (by clicking to close the lightbox) and is still draggable through it.

I tried setting a higher z-index for the lightbox than the draggable div but it had no effect.

How can I solve this?

```
<div class="header">

   <Input Id="tab1" Type="radio" Name="tabs" Checked>
   <label for="tab1">Play</label>

   <input id="tab2" type="radio" name="tabs">
   <label for="tab2">News</label>

   <input id="tab3" type="radio" name="tabs">
   <label for="tab3">Mods</label>

   <input id="tab4" type="radio" name="tabs">
   <label for="tab4">Tools</label>

   <div class="controls">
       <Input type="radio" name="tabs">
       <label id="refresh" for="tab9">&nbsp;</label>
       <Input type="radio" name="tabs">
       <label id="config" for="tab10">&nbsp;</label>
       <Input type="radio" name="tabs">
       <label id="close" for="tab11" style="font-size:23px;">&nbsp;</label>
   </div>

    <section id="content1"></section>
    <section id="content2"></section>
    <section id="content3"></section>
    <section id="content4"></section>

</div>


<script>

    // Variables ...
    var gui = require('nw.gui');
    var win = gui.Window.get();

    // Show once loaded ...
    $(window).on("load", function() {
        win.show();
    });

    // Close button control ...
    $("#close").click(function() {
        win.close();
    });

    // Refresh button control ...
    $("#refresh").click(function() {
        win.reloadIgnoringCache();
    });

    $content = '\
    <div id="configbox"><div class="header"></div></div>\
    ';

    // Config screen ...
    $("#config").featherlight($content);

 </script>
```

And...

```
div.header {
   background-color: #252525;
   font: 17px/1 'Saira Extra Condensed', sans-serif;
   -webkit-app-region: drag;
   text-transform: uppercase;
   font-weight: bold;
   display: inline-block;
   z-index: 1;
   padding: 0px;
   width: 100%;
   height: 40px;
}
```

And...

```
.featherlight {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    cursor: default;
    background: #333;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)
}
.featherlight:last-of-type {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .6)
}
```

Comment: Please add your HTML.

Comment: Added the HTML.